# How to assign dlsym()'s return value to function type?

Tags: c, gcc, function-pointers, freebsd, strict-aliasing

My problem is as follows:

I have a structure containing function pointers like this:

```
typedef void (CALLING_COVNENTION * functionType_t) (/*...*/);

typedef struct myFuncpointerStruc_s
{
    /*...*/
    functionType_t funcIdentifier;
    /*...*/
}myFuncpointerStruc_t;
```

Now I want to assign a functionpointer of exactly that type to it.
But sadly `dlsym()` is returning a `void *` instead of something like `function_poitner_type`

So my first try:

```
functionscope ()
{
    myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier;

    structIdentifier.funcIdentifier= dlsym (hAndle, "calledName");
}
```

ended in the warning:

> WARNING: ISO C forbids assignment between function pointer and 'void *'

Ok, that confused me... gcc was never talking that harsh to me.
But OK lets get tricky I thought there will probably be any backdoor to keep it standard conform. So I tried this:

```
functionscope ()
{
    myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier;

    *(void **) &structIdentifier.funcIdentifier = dlsym (hAndle, "calledName");
}
```

Hm.... obviously...

> warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict aliasing rules

As I don't know what happens `dlsym()` internally I can't know I will break, as I get returned a real `void *` that aliases my function, or something quite different, can I?

So I cant know, will the use of this function pointer now break strict-aliasing rules or won't it?

But anyway: For my company it is law to use the compilerflag `-fstrict-aliasing`.
So this is also not a possible solution for me, even if it would be conform.

So I tried it by going on.

My next idea was: what about to parse a `char *` version of `dlsym()` into memcopy?

The result:

```
functionscope ()
{
    myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier;

    unsigned char *localTestPtr = ((unsigned char *) dlsym (hAndle, "calledName");  

    memcpy (g_interfaceSvCheck.pfnPFD_SVCHK_GET_VERSION, localTestPtr, sizeof (localTestPtr));
}
```

The warning I'm getting now is pretty specific again:

> warning: ISO C forbids passing argument 1 of ´memcpy´ between function pointer and ´void *´

So my next idea was kind of "lets go back to the bytes" maybe there I will get a way it will be working on.
(But slowly I'm running out of ideas...)

So I did:

```
functionscope ()
{
    size_t testIndex;
    myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier;
    unsigned char *localTestPtr = ((unsigned char *) dlsym (hAndle, "calledName");

    for (testIndex = 0; testIndex < sizeof (localTestPtr); testIndex++)
    {
        ((unsigned char *)(structIdentifier.funcIdentifier))[testIndex] = ((unsigned char *)&localTestPtr)[testIndex];
    }

}
```

This ended in a quiet different warning:

> WARNING: ISO C forbids conversion of function pointer to object pointer type

So finally my freakiest try was:

```
functionscope ()
{
    size_t testIndex;
    myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier;
    unsigned char *localTestPtr = ((unsigned char *) dlsym (hAndle, "calledName");  
    unsigned char * FakeFunctionPointer;

    FakeFunctionPointer = 
        (((unsigned char *)structIdentifier) + offsetof (myFuncpointerStruc_t , funcIdentifier));

    for (testIndex = 0; testIndex < sizeof (localTestPtr); testIndex++)
    {
        FakeFunctionPointer[testIndex] = ((unsigned char *)&localTestPtr)[testIndex];
    }
}
```

And even here the problem is, that `offsetoff`'s second parameter can't get converted to `void *` as it is a function pointer.

I'm stucked and don't know how to get further, could anyone help me please finding a solution?

I just have these warnings by using gcc 4.2 not with clang.

The targeted C version is `-std=c99` to avoid is `-std=POSIX` and `-std=gnu99`

But this gcc warnings don't sound outdated to me.
I'm working currently on FreeBSD and I have really no idea left how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of tricky:

```
#define CALLING_CONVENTION 

typedef void (CALLING_CONVENTION * functionType_t) (/*...*/);
typedef struct myFuncpointerStruc_s
{
  /*...*/
  functionType_t funcIdentifier;
  /*...*/
} myFuncpointerStruc_t;

int main()
{
  myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier = {0};

  {
    functionType_t * pfuncIdentifier = &structIdentifier.funcIdentifier;

    *(void **) (pfuncIdentifier) = dlsym(handle, "calledName");
  }

  ...
}
```

The above solution just tricks to compiler. The does **not** work from `-O1` on anymore ... :-(

---

As there indeed is no solution, the only solution is to calm down the compiler. And the GNU people showed insight on this and invented: `__attribute__ ((__may_alias__))`

Here we can use it as follows:

```
#define CALLING_CONVENTION 

typedef void * __attribute__ ((__may_alias__)) pvoid_may_alias_t;

typedef void (CALLING_CONVENTION * functionType_t) (/*...*/);
typedef struct myFuncpointerStruc_s
{
  /*...*/
  functionType_t funcIdentifier;
  /*...*/
} myFuncpointerStruc_t;

int main()
{
  myFuncpointerStruc_t structIdentifier = {0};

  *(pvoid_may_alias_t *) (&structIdentifier.funcIdentifier) = dlsym(handle, "calledName");
  }

  ...
}
```

---

And btw: Where does `ldsym()` come from? I only know `dlsym()`.

Comment: before you (deleted?) your question I wrote already an comment: I said I never noticed that i mixed the 2 letters in my own define. currently `ldsym()` is a define of mine  switching between `dlsym()` and `GetProcAddress()`. So thanks, I fixed it here allready to avoid confusion. But your solution looks to me as would it produce a type punning warning. But anyway, I got to go check that.

Comment: By the way, is it your intension of holding functionType_t funcIdentifier; in a inner scope as you do the assignment? Didn't try so far but this looks to me as the compiler wont even find funcIdentifierwhen you do the assignement? will he?

Comment: Well both cases behavied as I expected. When I use the block scope as you (probably unintended) made in your snippet, I get "undeclared first use in function of `funcIdentifier`" + "type-punning" warning in the other case I get the type-punning warning anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your eddit again, but in this line `*(void **) (&funcIdentifier) = ldsym(hAndle, "calledName");` I still get the type punning warning, as I'm trying to alias a void type by function type. +1 so far, as this is a solution which would help some one who can ignore aliasing rules. But still isn't the solution for me.

Comment: Awesome one! At all no warnings in clang nor gcc. But it looks still like type punning to me, isn't it? As I'm getting anyway a void to function pointer conversion. Or is there any low level language difference between this one and passing directly to the structures member function pointer? would be awesome if you could explain in your answer whats the difference to it and why probbably here no warning attempts. Anyway a nice idea so far, so feel free to explain ( I would love to read the explanation)

Comment: *sigh* .. its just tricking the compiler, try with `-O2`. But I have the ultimate solution here by hand, and will be updatin gmy answer soon.

Comment: Hm ohkay, I was looking for a solution which is conform to the standard and not jsut tricking the compiler. But at all, if there is no better option I will have to turn off strict aliasing for this source file. But I'm looking forward for your update.

Comment: Ah ok, thats at least for this case a nice solution. thanks for your ambition and your spent time.

Answer (score 1):

Use two type-casts:

```
func_type *funptr;
funptr= (func_type *)(intptr_t)dlsym();
```

Type-casting funptr will cause troubles if size of code-pointers and data-pointers aren't equal.

Comment: That worked for me, except I used `uintptr_t`